FormBuilder: alterFields afform entity
I would like to ask how to use alterFields in existing (already in core) Activity afformEntity. I don't think I can override it so I used civi.afform_admin.metadata and was able to use alterFields. But these alterFields doesn't seem to be used when the public form is being viewed. Thank you
Is there something I am missing.

i expect i am not understanding, but many FB are built from SearchKits - so i wonder if what you are trying to alter could be done in the SK

@petednz-fuzion thanks for the feedback. Sorry for not having a more detailed information.
-For now I used afform metadata hook to alter the entity. I just had a field that was using OptionValue entity which was not populating the data on drop down. So had to use api4 entity of the preferred entity.
-But since the fk_entity is not carried over to rendered page, I also used alterAngular hook to correct the needed fk_entity.
-P.S. Is it possible to add js scripts in alterAngular hook for afform public page? The purpose is to handle onChange.
